# discord py music bot

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import youtube_dl
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    await voice_client.disconnect()

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    voice_client = guild.voice_client
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Ignoring exception in command join:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\hahuibala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\hahuibala\Desktop\py\bot.py", line 73, in join
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hahuibala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\hahuibala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hahuibala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of that

```py
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Could you explain ?